# Check pathname for Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got a question:

This code snippet works great:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if(pathname.indexOf( 'word1' ) > -1){
        // do something    
    }     
});
```

But if i want to check for array of word´s it doesnt work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    var myArray1 = new Array( "word1","word2","word3","word4" );
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if(pathname.indexOf( myArray1 ) > -1){
        // never executed!   why? 
    }     
});
```

Anybody could help with this problem? Greetings!

Comment: `if (myArray1.indexOf(pathname) != -1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a built in method for that, `$.inArray` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){         

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    if ( $.inArray(pathname, ["word1","word2","word3","word4"] ) != -1 ) {

         // do stuff

    }     
});
```

then there's regex

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    if ( /(word1|word2|word3|word4)/.test(window.location.pathname) ) {
         // do stuff
    }     
});
```

Comment: If you wanna get fancy you can do the !!~ pattern for any indexOf type functions:

if(!!~$.inArray(pathname, [...])) {

Comment: But `$.inArray("word1 word2", ["word1","word2","word3","word4"])` won't match, is that what OP wants?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test `pathname` against an array of values, I suggest looping. You cannot send in an array object as an argument to the `indexOf()` method. You can only send strings.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    var myArray1 = new Array( "word1","word2","word3","word4" );
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    for(stringy in myArray1){
        if(pathname.indexOf( stringy ) > -1){
            console.log('Match Found');
        }   
    }       
});
```

Look here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop to iterate over arrays (not `for...in`). `stringy` doesn't even refer to the element in the array, but the index.

Answer (score 0):

`string.indexOf` doesn't take array as a parameter, you should handle it yourself,

Ok I will make it a little bit different, you can also do this with Regex,

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
    var myArray1 = new Array( "word1","word2","word3","word4" );
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if (pathname.match(new RegExp(myArray1.join("|")))) {
       // yes, there is at least one match.
    }
});
```

I don't know whether if you want it to match all words in the array.

Comment: Use a normal `for` loop to iterate over arrays (not `for...in`).

Comment: @FelixKling Is a ```for(string in array)``` fine?

Comment: @Cygwinnian: In general, no: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` looks for occurrences of a given string in another string. So you can't invoke it with an array as parameter. You must invoke it several times, each one with a string as parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
   var myArray1 = new Array( "word1","word2","word3","word4" );
   var pathname = window.location.pathname;
   for(var i=0; i<myArray1.length; i++) {
      if(pathname.indexOf( myArray1[i] ) > -1){
       // will be executed
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) for this:

```
if ($.grep(myArray1, function(word) {
    return pathname.indexOf(word) != -1;
})) {
    // do something
}
```

Or, use native functions:

```
if (myArray1.some(function(word) {
    return pathname.indexOf(word) != -1;
})) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a way to test `n` quantities of pathnames.

```
import pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';

const ALLOWED_PATHS = [
  'test',
  'test/:param'
]

const allowed = ALLOWED_PATHS.map((path) => {
  const regex = pathToRegexp(path)
  return regex.test(window.location.pathname);
});

if(allowed.some(Boolean)) {
  // Match
} else {
  // Not Match
}

...
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Pure Vanilla JavaScript functional approach

```js
const AllowedPaths = [
  "abc",
  "/js", //<-- true
  "cpe/boom"
];

const notEmtpy = ( arr ) => arr.some( item => item !== null );
const allowed = ( arr ) => {
  let res = notEmtpy(arr.map((path) => window.location.pathname.match(path) ));
  if(!res) return false
  return true
}

console.log("Current Path: ", window.location.pathname)
console.log( "Is URL matched ? ", allowed(AllowedPaths))
```